# Which package have usbconfig in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

On Ubuntu 14.04, after type in terminal usbconfig
say: usbconfig: command not found .
Search by apt-cache search usbconfig 
has no output result.
Which package has usbconfig app?

Comment: What is your purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `usbconfig` is used on FreeBSD only, the equivalent for Ubuntu is `lsusb`. `lsusb` should be installed by default but if it is not on your system you can install it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install usbutils
```

**References:**

- [Get Linux and FreeBSD hardware info with guide to commands](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/get-linux-and-freebsd-hardware-info-with-guide-to-commands/)
- [Linux USB utilities](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/usbutils)

Comment: `lsusb` is installed by default.

Comment: Lsusb it, fair app. Moreove I, look, look for  app that manage usb_quirck module.